# Plot vertical graphs, gnuplot. Rotate xlabel and key

Tags: graph, graphics, rotation, gnuplot

First of all I would like to apologize for the text, my English is a bit rusty.

So I have a problem plotting a chart and it's been a long time consuming. The chart is below.

This graph is generated from a fit of a normal distribution relative to a data file.

I wanted to plot the gaussians at y, not at x. Make these chart vertical. I researched several things and did not find it. Then I had the idea of ​​rotating it in \TeX, but for that I would have to turn the labels, the tics, and the key.

I use epslatex, so I had issues with transparency. I solved this problem using cairolatex (which generated the figure below). Resolved the transparency, I went to turn all tics and the labels.

First question, how does xlabel spin, I did
**set xlabel '$E_p [meV]$' rotate by 180**
and it did not work, so my solution was to make a
**unset xlabel
set label '$E_p$ [meV]' at 30.5,-550 rotate by 180**
and adjust the position, which is nothing practical.

The second question, of which I did not find any solution is, how to turn the key?

Follow the figures for a better understanding ...

Thank you...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `set parametric` to plot such functions which cannot be written as `y(x)`. In the parametric mode you must specify functions `x(t)` and `y(t)` for both coordinates. The range of the dummy variable `t` is controlled by `set trange`. A simple example is

```
set parametric
set trange [-4:4]
set autoscale yfix
y(t) = t
x(t) = t**2
plot x(t), y(t) with lines
```

Here, the `set autoscale yfix` automatically adjusts the yrange to the range of `y(t)`, which is desired in this case. The xrange is autoscaled as usual.

[image]

So, an extension of the above example for gaussians with some eye candy could be

```
reset
set samples 1000
set style fill  transparent solid 0.50 noborder
set style function filledcurves x1=0
set xlabel "Counts"
set ylabel "Energy"
Gauss(x,mu,sigma) = 1./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp( -(x-mu)**2 / (2*sigma**2) )
d1(x) = Gauss(x, 0.5, 0.5)
d2(x) = Gauss(x,  2.,  1.)
d3(x) = Gauss(x, -1.,  2.)
set encoding utf8
set parametric
set trange [-8:8]
set autoscale yfix
plot d1(t),t title "μ =  0.5 σ = 0.5",\
     d2(t),t title "μ =  2.0 σ = 1.0",\
     d3(t),t title "μ = -1.0 σ = 2.0"
```

[image]

Comment: The solution you presented is very good.

He solved my problem, very quickly.

With set sample 1000 it was half grid, I increased it to 20000 to be cool, only appeared white lines, very discreet.

Comment: With version 5.2 you shouldn't get any white lines. That was a problem with filledcurves in previous versions.